# How Do I get unbound to only use DNSSEC?

Tags: freebsd, pfsense, dnssec

I have a pfsense box, that I am in the process of configuring for the first time I would like to use DNSSEC.

[I used this site to check my DNSSEC status](http://dnssectest.sidnlabs.nl/test.php).

When I go to this site I am told that my "DNSSEC is configured in "permissive mode" I would like it to be in a secure or validation mode.

In my pfsense config I have enabled unbound dnssec. [I have also run Unbound-anchor as described here](https://www.unbound.net/documentation/unbound-anchor.html).

I don't seem to be getting any errors, but I do not have DNSSEC. I would like to have DNSSEC.

I am only concerned about the DNS data that I receive, I'm not putting any address onto the internet.

I'm happy to use the GUI, but CLI is fine by me as well.